How do i resolve CORS error and allow all with firebase genkit cloud functions
I deployed my firebase genkit flow to google cloud function. I have set httpOptions: {cors: true} as well as cors: '*' and even listed out all the allowable sites but I am still running into CORS error when triggering my function.
I even tried to setGlobalOptions for cloud functions.

setGlobalOptions({
  region: "us-central1",
});

defineSecret("GOOGLE_GENAI_API_KEY");

configureGenkit({
  plugins: [
    firebase(),
    vertexAI(),
    dotprompt(),
  ],
  logLevel: "debug",
  enableTracingAndMetrics: true,
});

export const carePlanGenerationFlow = onFlow(
  {
    name: "carePlanGenerationFlow",

    inputSchema: z.object({
      content: z.string(),
      sourceUrl: z.string(),
    }),

    outputSchema: z.any(),
    httpsOptions: {
      // tried setting cors: '*'
      // and also ['http://127.0.0.1:7001','https://xyx.com/, 'https://us-central-xyz.cloudfunctions.net']
      // but nothing works
      cors: true,
    },

Spent several hours looking at examples, reading docs and tried a bunch of solutions mentioned above but nothing is working.

the preflight check response header "Allow-Control-Cross-Origin" was missing

Facing the same issue, any conclusion on this?

any update on this?
